# Error in build Flutter app (Encountered error while building for device.)

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, build

I tried to deploy the app by building the Flutter app through 'flutter build ipa', but an error occurred. How can I fix this error?
"
Error (Xcode):
'/Users/choimoonkee/Desktop/FlutterCMK/ars_vivendi_fit_buddy/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app
/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.ap
p/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.a
pp/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.
app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner
.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runne
r.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runn
er.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app' is longer than filepath buffer size (1025).
"

The path on the Xcode is default.

"Changing current working directory to: /Users/choimoonkee/Desktop/FlutterCMK/ars_vivendi_fit_buddy
Building com.arsvivendi.trainer4u for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: AB769F2U8P
Running Xcode build...
└─Compiling, linking and signing...                        641ms
Xcode build done.                                           66.9s
Failed to build iOS app"

Comment: Build output errors look similar to Bug Filed on Flutter github https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30287 , perhaps try the advice in the comments `"remove Runner from Copy Bundle Resources and uncheck the membership."`